# Convert file path to web url with windows batch or powershell commands

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I need to make a batch file converts a windows file path to web url.

For example, if I run this command

```
C:\>tourl.bat "C:\Users\Public\Music\sample.mp3"
```

It should print out this.

```
http://localhost/Users/Public/Music/sample.mp3
```

Anyone can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

```
@echo off

set "$var=%~1"
set $var="http://localhost%$var:~2%"
set "$var=%$var:\=/%"
echo %$var%
```

Comment: Why you use a dollar sign before the variable name? Yes, I know in which language this is _required_, but Batch file novice programmers may incorrectly think that the dollar sign is required in Batch file variables (the Batch file syntax is complex enough already).

Comment: I know @Aacini you're right, but that's my way of coding.

Comment: @SachaDee the $ in front of a variable name is not a big deal IMO. But to Aacini's point it is probably good to distinguish between the way you do things and what might be more canonical for the purposes of SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
 "C:\Users\Public\Music\sample.mp3" -replace 'C\:\\Users','http://localhost' `
                                    -replace '\/','/'
```